# Ember data and mongodb state?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

According to http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html

> Records without an id property are not considered embedded records, model instances must have an id property to be used with Ember Data.

If thats so how would i use a model like:

```
 {
    "_id": "545b54f20dbd7015f015359a", 
    "comments": [
        {
            "msg": "what is this jelly", 
            "time": "1415271666", 
            "user": {
                "id": "53fefc9ee4b07d3fe92fc077", 
                "username": "kfir124"
            }
        }
    ], 
    "files": [
        {
            "key": "1415271653.39af9c9fb8cc8b49dcaac5eec72614ce85.jpg", 
            "order": 0
        }
    ], 
    "time": "1415271666", 
    "uploader": {
        "id": "53fefc9ee4b07d3fe92fc077", 
        "username": "kfir124"
    }
}
```

So uploader may be an embedded record but what about **files** and **comments**? they are both arrays of objects which **do not live** outside of the main model's namespace therefore they have no IDs